# No module named yum

Tags: centos, yum, python

I am facing errors while running any yum commands on centos 7 system

```
No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.11 (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:44:20)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

The last thing I was doing before I encountered this error was
cpanm --notest XML::LibXML
Not sure if that disturbed the python configs in any way.
I went through the forums and updated python rpms for centos 7

```
$ ls rpm/
python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-tools-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm
tix-devel-8.4.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum-3.4.3-132.el7.centos.0.1.noarch.rpm.1
python-devel-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm 
tkinter-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.31-34.el7.noarch.rpm
python-libs-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm
tix-8.4.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm 
yum-3.4.3-132.el7.centos.0.1.noarch.rpm  yum-utils-1.1.31-34.el7.noarch.rpm

$ sudo rpm -ivh  *.rpm --force
```

Here is the output of the following commands

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.11
$ rpm -qi python
Name        : python
Version     : 2.7.5
Release     : 34.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Tue 29 Mar 2016 01:29:30 AM EDT
Group       : Development/Languages
Size        : 80835
License     : Python
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Wed 25 Nov 2015 10:33:01 AM EST, Key ID 24c6a8a7f4a80eb5
Source RPM  : python-2.7.5-34.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 19 Nov 2015 09:33:15 PM EST
Build Host  : worker1.bsys.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : http://www.python.org/
Summary     : An interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language


$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ vim /usr/bin/yum

#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
```

**Can someone please help me out in recovering the yum command?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get that python rpm from? Why did you install it? And why --force?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I installed the RPMs as this was the suggested fix for older versions of centos. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272827/no-module-named-yum?noredirect=1#comment473751_272827.  I tried sudo rpm -ivh  *.rpm  command several times. With and without --force.  Python tar from:  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Was this before or after you started getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The python executable you're using seems suspicious to me; I don't have a CentOS machine handy to check, but my recollection is that the system-provided one should be in `/usr/bin/python`.

If you run

```
[$]> rpm -qf /usr/local/bin/python
```

Does it report the file is owned by the `python` package?

Also, what is the output of

```
[$]> rpm -ql python | grep bin
```

Comment: I finally reverted to an older working image as none of the fixes seemed to be working . Thanks all for guiding me and giving your suggestions. For completeness:
    ]$rpm -qf /usr/local/bin/python
    file /usr/local/bin/python is not owned by any package
    ]$ rpm -ql python | grep bin
    /usr/bin/pydoc
    /usr/bin/python
    /usr/bin/python2
    /usr/bin/python2.7
In the broken system the python version everywhere was 2.7.11, but on the working system
     /usr/bin/python -V
    Python 2.7.5
    /usr/local/bin/python -V
    Python 2.7.11

Comment: Yeah, so you had installed two versions of python - one through the package manager (`/usr/bin/python`) and one somehow else (`/usr/local/bin/python`).  Yum seems to have been using the latter one, which didn't have the yum libraries installed in its search path.